# To use or not to use targetsdkVersion 23

Tags: java, android, api

My compilesdkversion is 23 and my targetSdkversion was 23.

I found targeting 23 is more difficult and slower than 21 (I haven't tried 22). Perhaps it seems that way because I always have to ask for permission from the user to use services such as 'location' and 'read contacts'. And everytime I test it out and give permission, it takes like a second longer to load the service versus using 21 which is just straight forward and faster.

Testing targetSdkVersion @ 21 on my android device (which is 6.0 Marshmallow) works really well and I thought it wouldn't since it's not the latest version.

So I'm just stumped on picking between version 21 and 23. Is 21 better because it's more straight forward and efficent or is 23 better because the user should be able to choose if they want to allow the app to use a certain service? Or perhaps none of this matters and it's fine to choose either or depending on what you like? :S

I just find 23 really nonsensical. I have no 'optional' services so I don't see the point in asking a user for permission to use their location to find where they are on a map. It should be expected from the user when the first downloaded the app.

Thank you for reading and please forgive me if my English is bad (2nd language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to continue targeting API 21 if you want, but doing so severely limits your ability to leverage new features in Android.

By refusing to target the latest API version, you opt your app of new platform features. The most obvious one in API 23 is runtime permissions, but by limiting yourself to 21 you also miss out on anything introduced in later versions as well. For example, Android N is introducing multi window mode.

The real impact here is to your users. While runtime permissions are more work for you as a developer, they are something that the vast majority of users favor over install-time permissions because it gives them more control over their device and their data.

Finally, keep in mind that even if you refuse to support runtime permissions, users with devices running API 23+ can still revoke permissions that your application requests. If they do so, you will get default data from any methods requiring those permissions and your application may not behave the way you expect.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I guess it's better for me to adapt to the newer versions. Thank you.